# Why does std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t> not work as defined?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, character-encoding, iostream

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f1()
{
    wcout.imbue(locale("chs"));
    wcout << L"您" << endl;
}

void f2()
{
    locale loc(wcout.getloc(), new codecvt<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t>());

    wcout.imbue(loc);
    wcout << L"好" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    f1(); // OK
    f2(); // Error. There is no output as expected.
}
```

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/codecvt/)'s online documentation:

```
codecvt<wchar_t,char,mbstate_t>: 

    converts between native wide and narrow character sets.
```

This program is compiled with VC++, and runs on Windows.

In this program, the internal character set is UCS-2, which is defined by the VC++ compiler; the external character set, i.e. the narrow character set, is GBK (a Chinese character set) in console environment. If the documentation is true, then `wcout` can convert the unicode string from UCS-2 to GBK as `f1()` does; however, it does not. Why?

Comment: Better documentation: [`std::codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've default-constructed an `std::codecvt`, with no particular conversion rules. It has no way of knowing that you want GBK and not GB18030 or UTF-8.

Ways to get a codecvt that converts wchar_t to GBK:

- Construct an `std::locale` for GBK just use that with your stream, no need to pull out a facet

  ```
  wcout.imbue(std::locale("")); // this uses the current user settings,
  wcout.imbue(std::locale("zn_CN.gbk")); // or name the locale explicitly,
                                         // by whatever name Windows calls it
  ```
- Construct the facet directly with `std::codecvt_byname`

  ```
  wcout.imbue(std::locale(wcout.getloc(),
              new std::codecvt_byname("zh_CN.gbk")); // explict name
  ```
- Write your own conversion routine and derive from `std::codecvt`, so you could use it with

  ```
  wcout.imbue(std::locale(wcout.getloc(), new yourcodecvt);
  ```

Windows support for C++ locales is very poor, though, WinAPI may have a more appropriate conversion function.